# SQL INNER JOIN ON and USING

Tags: sql

Say I have  tables and I join them with inner join. What is the advantage of using "ON" over "USING". Or are they the same in all sense?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`USING` is an equijoin and causes duplicate columns to be removed from the resultset (arguably this makes it "more relational").

`ON` is a theta join (i.e. join condition need not be equality and may involve columns with differing names) and allows duplicate columns to appear in the resultset.

Answer (score 16):

`USING` requires the names of the columns in both tables to be identical:

```
SELECT *
FROM   employee 
   INNER JOIN department 
      USING (DepartmentID);
```

whereas `ON` allows you to designate any columns to join on:

```
SELECT *
FROM   employee 
   JOIN department 
      ON employee.DepartmentID = department.ID;
```

In short, `USING` is more succinct, but `ON` is more flexible.

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Equi-join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Equi-join)

Comment: And in general I think that if you wrote `USING` most reading what you had written would have to look up the definition of the keyword.

Comment: Also in the article, the columned joined with `USING` will only appear once in the result set, rather than twice (once for each table)

Answer (score 6):

Not all flavors of SQL have USING so it is less portable as well as being a rare way to query.

Comment: I was wondering why I've never heard of it before, and apparently 'The USING clause is not supported by SQL Server and Sybase." -Wikipedia.  It seems convenient though.

Comment: `USING` in this context does not appear to be available in DB2 for the iSeries.